# Why doesn't my background image show up in the html tag?

Tags: html, css, background-image

I'm having problems adding a background image to my background website in the html tag.
The problem is here:

```
html{
background:url('assets/img/jp-logo.png'); /*background image*/
background-image:url('assets/img/jp-logo.png'); /*background image*/
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
}
```

I put in both background and background image because i testing whether either one would work along with the background size: cover but none of them did. I also checked my file directory paths, those are good too. I was wondering why as that's not supposed to happen. i tested it on a seaprate html and css test sheet and it worked, but why not here is suspicious to me. The full code here: http://jsfiddle.net/TheAmazingKnight/kjLg8/

This short sample I made worked:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Test Page</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="test.css" type="text/css" media="screen" /> <!--CSS for desktop screens-->
</head>
<body>
    <p>hello</p>
    <img src="jp-logo.png" alt="jp-logo.png" />
</body>
</html>

html{
background-image:url('assets/img/jp-logo.png');
}
```

Comment: For external files (CSS and JavaScript) use the 'resources' tab on the left hand pane of JS Fiddle. The HTML panel is to contain the contents of the `body` element (*not* the `head`, or `body`, tags themselves).

Comment: Are you running your sample from the same folder that the problematic file exists?

Comment: Adding a valid image (with/without quotes) works for me: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/davidcl64/kjLg8/4/) (also gave html 100% height to ensure it filled the window)

Answer (score 1):

`html` has no semantic value. Use `body` instead. You may want to give your `body` a `margin:0;`.

Comment: Your're wrong, I just said the html tags worked on the test page. Copy and Paste the sample and you'll see, it works.

Comment: I've found this post useful in the past:  [Understanding the HTML versus BODY Element in CSS](http://phrogz.net/css/htmlvsbody.html)

Answer (score 1):

I changed your background photo and placed into body element like this:

```
body{

    background:url(http://technomarketer.typepad.com/technomarketer//Radiohead_wallpaper.jpg); /*background image*/

-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
```

and it worked.

So, maybe your path to the photo (assets/img/jp-logo.png) is wrong.

Did you check it?

Answer (score 0):

```
html{
background:url("assets/img/jp-logo.png") no-repeat center center fixed;
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;
}
```

I found that this code works perfect and to give credit where credit is due:
http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/

Answer (score -1):

if you want to write css code inside html page be like this

```
<head>
<title>hello</title>
<style type="text/css">
html{
background: url(photo.jpg);
}
</style>
</head>
```

and the image url not between quotation mark 'image.jpg' 
and it`s better to use body instead of html

Comment: I understand but the image still does not show up even in the body tag. I think something's wrong or glitched up.

Comment: "it`s better to use body instead of html" - that all depends on what you are trying to do.

Comment: I'm simply just trying to make a background-image and it fails on me every time on the body or html tag. Any resolution? :(